# What is Volume Policy in android?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am developing an android app in which i want to mute the voice of receive person voice.i am trying to do this thing using the Audio manager. In Audio manager class  doc mentioned that if device is using the volume policy then all the method which are using for volume control will not work.so please tell me what is volume policy. [this is link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isVolumeFixed()) .

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
               audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL );
```